# Creating straight line that starts from the point with the given length and also rotates around the point in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, polyline-creation, geometry-conversion, rotate

I want to create a straight line that starts from the point with the given length. And also it rotates around the point.

I have a point data of cctvs:

[image: point data of cctv]

And I want to create a line with the given length of 50 meters on each point that rotates at 5 degrees.

To help understand the result would be like this picture for each point.

[image: rotate line]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Geometry by expression.

This will create a point projected from the center point in the directions 0, 5, 10, 15, ..., 355
at 50 m distance, then draw a line from the center point and the projected point:

```
collect_geometries( 
array_foreach(array:=generate_series( 0, 355, 5),
expression:= 
 make_line($geometry,  
 project( point:=$geometry, distance:=50, azimuth:=radians(@element)
 ))))
```

[image]

It will be a multiline, you can explode it to singlepart lines with [Multipart to singleparts](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgismultiparttosingleparts)